# Accessing the segments of a path in akka-http out of a RequestContext?

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm looking for a way to access, in a method, the list of segments of the path of a request with akka-http:

```
val route = Seq(
  path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { sub }
).reduce(_~_)

def sub(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
  // how to have access to the two IntNumbers?
}(request)
```

I know I could just get them straight out in the routing code:

```
path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) => sub(a, b) }
...
def sub(a: Int, b: Int)(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = get {
...
```

but I would like to keep my routing code clean.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify it visually...

**Step 1:**

Start with:

```
path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) => sub(a, b) }

def sub(a: Int, b: Int)(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = ???
```

Don't explicitly pass arguments, Scala will do it for you.

So this:

```
path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) => sub(a, b) }
```

Becomes this:

```
path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { sub }
```

**Step 2:**

Since we have this definition:

```
type Route = RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]
```

We can replace this part `(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult]` of `sub` method with `Route`.

So this:

```
def sub(a: Int, b: Int)(request: RequestContext): Future[RouteResult] = ???
```

Becomes this:

```
def sub(a: Int, b: Int): Route = ???
```

Or if you prefer this style:

```
val sub: (Int, Int) => Route = { (a, b) => ??? }
```

**Usage example:**

```
path("api" / "sub" / IntNumber / IntNumber) { sub }

def sub(a: Int, b: Int): Route = complete(s"$a / $b")

val sub: (Int, Int) => Route = { (a, b) => complete(s"$a / $b") }
```

Note that visually it looks a bit simpler but functionally and in terms of type signatures it's basically the same.

Comment: Hi, from a code transformation perspective you're absolutely right. My question was more along the lines of if there was a way of easily getting that info out of the RequestContext without having to rely on the passed in variables.

Comment: If you match and extract parts of path with `IntNumber` directives then it makes sense to use those extracted values like in the code above, but if you want to delay extraction you can just push it down the route processing simply like this: `path("api" / "sub" ) { sub }` and `def sub: Route = path( IntNumber / IntNumber) { (a, b) => complete(s"$a / $b") }`. Is that what you looking for?